# Can I use a plugin for a singular page on my website?

Tags: plugins, html, content, cms

I have used just html/css/php from scratch for my site but for the events page I haven't found a way to do it simply.

I searched online and found this: https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/screenshots/

and I want to use it just for the single events page rather than use wordpress for the whole site.

Is it possible to just use wordpress for a page and not my whole site?

Comment: you are not using WordPress?

Comment: I'm not using wordpress for the rest of my site

Comment: that's really strange that you want to setup a whole new environment just for using a plugin on a single page, you should create this instead, if you install WordPress you'll have to customize it accordingly to match the design with your static site.

Comment: @ArsalanMithani If he does that he might as well power the whole site with wordpress. Definitely an option that I would recommend, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: yes that's not an answer, but he is asking just for a page, if he want to convert the whole site, that can be ok, but would you recommend this just for a page?

Comment: Not for one page no, It can be done, but its a lot of overhead and work for little gain.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is definitely possible.

> Although technically ***it'll not be just a single event page, rather an event directory***. Under that directory there will be single event links created by the [event plugin](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/screenshots/) you've mentioned. However, those single event links will not have any physical static files, rather those will be managed by WordPress internally.
>
> I understand that you've mentioned ***single page*** in your question, however, for the use case, it's most likely that you don't actually need just a single page, rather a separate directory for WordPress for those events.

So, for example, your site is `example.com` and you have many custom `html` & `php` files in your site. Now you want to create a new page named `my-events` and want to manage the events using [WordPress](https://wordpress.org) & [The Events Calendar Plugin](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/screenshots/), in a way that'll not affect the existing files.

In that case:

1. Create a new directory in your web root named `my-events` so that it can be reached by `example.com/my-events/` URL. (the name of the directory can be anything you want, but to avoid conflict, it should be a new directory that'll only have WordPress related files)
2. Now you install WordPress in that `my-events` directory.
3. Delete sample post / page / category etc. created by WordPress by default.
4. Now you install The Event Calendar plugin in your WordPress installation.
5. Create your events.
6. Set `events` archive page (created by the plugin) as your WordPress Front Page.

That's it. Now all the static files of your site will work as before & WordPress will serve your `events` from the `example.com/my-events/` directory.

It's possible to do further customisations, but that's out of the scope of this answer.

Comment: also mention that the default theme will be used, & the event page will look different from the rest of the site, he will have to  customize the files  (like header / footer etc) to make it look like the rest of the site.

Comment: @ArsalanMithani yes that's true, but that's not part of the question. Many people use WordPress in sub-directory for a very specific purpose & use other software for other things. That's OK. After that it's up to the site owner on how he wants the design to be - similar or different.

Comment: @Fayyaz agreed, but in my opinion it is better to mention, many newbies don't know that, defining the method on how to do it, is surely not a part of the question but mentioning is surely relevant to it, so they can decide what would be better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that but you will need to style the wordpress site to match your site. If you take that time you should run the whole site on wordpress.

Alternatively take a look at [CodeCanyon](https://codecanyon.net/). There are a number of event calendar scripts there that would be lighter than a whole wordpress install. Read carefully and check the reviews. Its a market site, not everything is excellent.

Comment: seriously i will not recommend the WordPress option just for a page, script integration may help but he will have to customize the code according to the requirement.

Comment: A dedicated script would be a lot less work then a whole wordpress install.  Thats why I suggested converting the whole site, I think it would be the easiest solution with a lot more potential. It would help maybe to see the site, we would have a better idea of how much work conversion or intergration would take.